# Best practice to manage file uploads in microservice architecture

Tags: microservices

I am new to the microservice architecture. After reading some microsoft tutorials, I am currently working on a practice project using api gateway to communicate to microservices. However, some of my services need to upload files (eg. User portraits, catalog images,etc) to a online cloud object storage. Should I use the API gateway to upload the files to storage and only sendfile links to microservices or transport the file stream to a COS microservice directly. It seems to me the latter one would expose to a much larger network bandwidth cost and wont work efficiently on large files.

Comment: _Should I use the API gateway to upload the files to storage_: doesn't that make your API gateway a microservice that contains actual logic? What were the responsibilities of API gateway in the first place?